# Are there any nice libraries / open source projects to implement a login system for users using php?

Tags: php

I need a login based user account system where the user data is in my hands.. So no openID.. Are there any libraries which provide this feature along with security.. I'm using php mysql btw..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`Zend_Auth`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.introduction.html)